# @synthesize interferes with inheritance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **FINAL EDIT**
>
> *The solution to all life's problems:*
>   [image]
>
> Switching xcode's "Compiler Version" setting to "LLVM compiler 2.0" solves this issue, many thanks to Firoze Lafeer for the concerted, constructive assistance!

Intention was to build some really basic functionality into all my classes by subclassing NSObject and UIViewController with something to grab the application delegate, extend the viewDidAppear mechanism a little, etc.  I've got a base class that looks something like this (only relevant lines included):

```
@interface PHView : UIViewController {
    id<PHAppDelegate> appDelegate;
}
-(id)init;
//some other method prototypes
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@end

@implementation PHView
@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    appDelegate = (id<PHAppDelegate>)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    visible = FALSE;
    initialized = FALSE;
    return self;
}
    //some other methods
@end
```

**EDIT** I should mention here that the property "delegate" isn't meant to point to ivar "appDelegate" or anything... I only left it in to illustrate that this superclass uses @synthesize.  Since it's not a related useage I *think* it doesn't matter, but I wouldn't say that I *know* that.

Interface for the subclass:

```
@interface PinMap : PHView <MKMapViewDelegate> {
//@interface PinMap : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
//    NSObject<PHAppDelegate>* appDelegate;
}
-(id)init;
-(void)zoomToUser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView* map;
@end
```

This compiles:

```
@implementation PinMap
//@synthesize map;

-(PinMap*) init{
    self = [super init];
    //appDelegate = (NSObject<PHAppDelegate>*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    return self;
}

-(void)zoomToUser {
    //MKCoordinateRegion region = map.region;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((CLLocationDegrees)300, (CLLocationDegrees)300), MKCoordinateSpanMake((CLLocationDegrees)20,(CLLocationDegrees)20)); //random region
    region.center = [[appDelegate location] coordinate];
    region.span.longitudeDelta /= 50.0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta /= 50.0;
//    [map setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

This does not compile:

```
@implementation PinMap
@synthesize map;

-(PinMap*) init{
    self = [super init];
    //appDelegate = (NSObject<PHAppDelegate>*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    return self;
}

-(void)zoomToUser {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = map.region;
    //MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((CLLocationDegrees)300, (CLLocationDegrees)300), MKCoordinateSpanMake((CLLocationDegrees)20,(CLLocationDegrees)20)); //random region
    region.center = [[appDelegate location] coordinate]; // <-- ERROR HERE
    region.span.longitudeDelta /= 50.0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta /= 50.0;
    [map setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

At the marked location, I get """'appDelegate' undeclared (first use in this function)"""  My first step was to Clean, reboot and Clean again (fixed three bugs this week using that procedure) and when that didn't work I started trying things that make sense, and eventually some things that DON'T make sense.

The following DOES compile (and run) but I honestly don't understand why:

```
@interface PinMap : PHView <MKMapViewDelegate> {
//@interface PinMap : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    //NSObject<PHAppDelegate>* appDelegate;
    MKMapView* _map;
}
-(id)init;
-(void)zoomToUser;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView* map;
@end

@implementation PinMap
@synthesize map=_map;

-(PinMap*) init{
    self = [super init];
    //appDelegate = (NSObject<PHAppDelegate>*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    return self;
}

-(void)zoomToUser {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = self.map.region;
    //MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((CLLocationDegrees)300, (CLLocationDegrees)300), MKCoordinateSpanMake((CLLocationDegrees)20,(CLLocationDegrees)20)); //random region
    region.center = [[appDelegate location] coordinate];
    region.span.longitudeDelta /= 50.0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta /= 50.0;
    [self.map setRegion:region animated:NO];
}
```

In this trim it'll respond to "self.map" but considers "map" to be undeclared.

**EDIT** The "self" requirement makes sense to me now, but the disappearing / reappearing "appDelegate" ivar is what I'm actually worried about.  Sorry if that was unclear before.  But seriously, what's up with that?

Comment: But isn't your reference to 'appDelegate' working fine now that you fixed the syntax error in the preceding line? If not, sorry I'm missing the part where it isn't working.

Comment: the reference to 'appDelegate' WAS the syntax error.  Supposedly it was undefined, but it magically reappeared when I removed @synthesize or explicitly attached an ivar.  With a simple "@synthesize map;" it got at map fine (accessing its implicit ivar correctly) but insisted 'appDelegate' didn't exist.

Comment: Ok, it's a bit confusing because you also show a version that does compile after you fixed the map issue. Perhaps you can show the current version of your code that doesn't compile, just to be sure we're looking at the same thing. You've edited code here, does it match what you have in code exactly?

Comment: Oh, and which compiler are you using?

Comment: This is an xcode project.  The last snippet is what I'm currently using, because it works.  The second-to-last snippet is what I'd prefer, 1) because I'd rather access my ivar directly and map_ is an awkward name, and 2) because it bothers me that I don't understand how map and appDelegate are interacting.

Comment: additionally, "map" was NEVER an issue.  I was curious why I needed to access it with "self" after the change and now I'm glad I asked, but at no time was it part of the problem.  The only reason I included it in the snippet at all is that changing its implimentation seems to affect appDelegate.

Comment: Xcode offers more than one compiler. If you'd like to take this to chat, I think I might know what's going on here.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Oh, fun. Well, pls let us know the version of Xcode you are using. Also, go to your project build settings under "build options" and see what compiler you are using. And lastly, change 'appDelegate' to 'self->appDelegate' (not self.appDelegate) and see if that changes things.

Comment: You were 100% correct about the compiler version issue, now editing the question to reflect the solution.  I guess I should've left my prejudice against blaming the compiler for my problems at the door when I entered Apple's Walled Garden.  I'll try to remember to +1 you for this when I have enough rep.

Comment: Ah, I bet I know which bug you just tripped over. :) Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, PinMap doesn't have an instance variable (ivar) called 'map'.

It has a property called 'map', which you can access like so:

```
region = self.map.region;
```

Or it has an ivar called _map. So you could do this:

```
region = _map.region;
```

But the former is recommended. You made a property, so you probably want to use it (outside of initXXX and dealloc)

**EDIT**

Also, the designated initializer for UIViewController is initWithNibName:bundle:

So just make sure if you subclass UIViewController that you call its designated initializer.

**EDIT AGAIN**

In those cases in your comment, you probably have an ivar and a property with the same name. If you just do @synthesize propname, that's what you get. But in this case you did @synthesize map = _map.

It's worth taking the time to understand when you are accessing the ivar directly, versus the property. Otherwise a lot of things won't make sense, and other bugs will happen. To access the property you **must** do 'self.propertyName' (or [self propertyName] or [self setPropertyName:something])

If you aren't using self, you aren't using the getter/setter (this is often a bad thing, if for example your getter/setter is doing your memory mgmt or initialization for you). You also have to use the actual ivar name if you aren't going to use the property.

**EDIT AGAIN AGAIN**

I see changing the compiler helped. I would suggest two things then: double check all of your @synthesize statements to make sure you aren't asking the compiler to synthesize an ivar in a subclass that already exists in a superclass. While you're sorting that out, I would recommend you name your ivars as variable_ or _variable so you can easily see where you are using the ivar versus the property.

And more importantly, you should really upgrade to LLVM 3.0, which is included in Xcode 4.2.1.

Comment: (at)property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* leftButton;
(at)property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* rightButton;
...
buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftButton, rightButton, nil];

It's never been a problem before.  This is the first time I've seen self be non-optional outside of scoped-out names.

Comment: See my edit about this. Instance variables and properties are two different things, even if you sometimes give them the same name.

Comment: Ok, that's pretty instructive about the "self" requirement.  I never really noticed it since I never use getter/setter methods in my own objects.  The disappearing "appDelegate" ivar is what I was worrying about, though, and I'm still really unclear on what that's all about.

Comment: Updated my answer with a couple other things to look at.

Comment: Well, I just let the ivars get set implicitly by \@synthesize as a sort of longhand for "public" since I feel complex setter functions are a brutally negative pattern.  As an example of why this is a smart approach, I know I didn't post-facto \@synthesize appDelegate because I know I never \@synthesized it at any time, ever.  It's not an \@property of anything; it has no _business_ being an \@property.  And if I ever try to cover its ivar, the compiler yells at me.  I even tried that on purpose when it thought appDelegate was undefined, it STILL yelled at me.

Answer (score 0):

`@synthesize` creates the setter and getter methods for a property, however it needs some place to store that object so you must add some sort of ivar to use @synthesize with a property

you can do

```
@interface ... : ... {
    Something* smth;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Something *smth;

@end

@implementation ...
@synthesize smth;
@end
```

or

```
@interface ... : ... {
    Something* _smth;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Something *smth;

@end

@implementation ...
@synthesize smth=_smth;
@end
```

Comment: "you must add some sort of ivar" - it's not a matter of "must" though maybe that's environment-specific?  Here in xcode4/ios you can do that implicitly if you (like me) get sick of typing everything three times.  My major malfunction re: needing to use self is that I thought accessing by simple name took you to your property (and it's getter/setter) whereas I'd been talking to implicit ivars all this time.

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the issue :P